# What's the difference between join and cogroup in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

What's the difference between join and cogroup in Apache Spark? What's the use case for each method?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

**Let me help you to clarify them, both are common to use and important!**

```
def join[W](other: RDD[(K, W)]): RDD[(K, (V, W))]
```

This is `prototype` of join, **please carefully look at it**. For example,

```
val rdd1 = sc.makeRDD(Array(("A","1"),("B","2"),("C","3")),2)
val rdd2 = sc.makeRDD(Array(("A","a"),("C","c"),("D","d")),2)
 
scala> rdd1.join(rdd2).collect
res0: Array[(String, (String, String))] = Array((A,(1,a)), (C,(3,c)))
```

All keys that will appear in the final result **is common to** rdd1 and rdd2. This is similar to `relation database operation INNER JOIN`.

**But cogroup is different**,

```
def cogroup[W](other: RDD[(K, W)]): RDD[(K, (Iterable[V], Iterable[W]))]
```

as one key at least appear in either of the two rdds, it will appear in the final result, let me clarify it:

```
val rdd1 = sc.makeRDD(Array(("A","1"),("B","2"),("C","3")),2)
val rdd2 = sc.makeRDD(Array(("A","a"),("C","c"),("D","d")),2)

scala> var rdd3 = rdd1.cogroup(rdd2).collect
res0: Array[(String, (Iterable[String], Iterable[String]))] = Array(
(B,(CompactBuffer(2),CompactBuffer())), 
(D,(CompactBuffer(),CompactBuffer(d))), 
(A,(CompactBuffer(1),CompactBuffer(a))), 
(C,(CompactBuffer(3),CompactBuffer(c)))
)
```

This is very `similar` to `relation database operation FULL OUTER JOIN`, but **instead of flattening the result per line per record, it will give you the `iterable interface` to you**, the following operation is **up to you as convenient**!

Good Luck!

Spark docs is: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions

Comment: How to use `cogroup` for large datasets like when I use `collect()` it throws out of memory exception `rdd1 = rdd2.cogroup(rdd3).collect`. Can you help on this issue [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180307/how-to-use-cogroup-for-large-datasets].Thank you

Comment: @Vignesh, please use take method instead of collect.

Comment: yh, tried with `take, top` do you know how to repartition the below code

Comment: `val source_primary_key = s.map(rec => (rec.split(",")(0), rec))
  val destination_primary_key = k.map(rec => (rec.split(",")(0), rec))
  val cos = source_primary_key.cogroup(destination_primary_key)`

Comment: @Vignesh, def cogroup[W](other: RDD[(K, W)], numPartitions: Int): RDD[(K,(Iterable[V], Iterable[W]))], you can directly add second parameter to the cogroup method.

Comment: Is "cogroup" less expensive than full outer join? Seems like cogroup just collects entires with the same key at the same task. I would get full shuffle read in the worst case, right?

Answer (score 0):

The join operation is similar to the SQL join operation. It combines two RDDs based on a common key and creates a new RDD containing pairs of elements with matching keys.
The syntax for join is:

```
RDD1.join(RDD2)
```

This operation is often used when you want to combine two RDDs based on a common key, similar to an inner join in SQL.

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, "apple"), (2, "banana"), (3, "cherry")))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, 10), (2, 20), (4, 40)))

val result = rdd1.join(rdd2)
result.collect().foreach(println)
```

o/p

```
(1,(apple,10))
(2,(banana,20))
```

The cogroup operation is a more generalized operation that allows you to group elements from multiple RDDs based on a common key, creating an RDD of tuples where the key is paired with the sequences of values from each RDD.
The syntax for cogroup is:

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, "apple"), (2, "banana"), (3, "cherry")))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, 10), (2, 20), (4, 40)))

val result = rdd1.cogroup(rdd2)
result.collect().foreach(println)
```

o/p

```
(1,(CompactBuffer(apple),CompactBuffer(10)))
(2,(CompactBuffer(banana),CompactBuffer(20)))
(3,(CompactBuffer(cherry),CompactBuffer()))
(4,(CompactBuffer(),CompactBuffer(40)))
```

join is more similar to an SQL join and creates pairs of elements with matching keys, while cogroup groups values by key from multiple RDDs, providing access to all values associated with a particular key in each RDD. The choice between them depends on your specific use case and the desired outcome.