# How to use groupByKey() on multiple RDDs?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have multiple RDDs with one common field `CustomerId`.

For eg:

`debitcardRdd` has data as `(CustomerId, debitField1, debitField2, ......)`

`creditcardRdd` has data as `(CustomerId, creditField1, creditField2, ....)`

`netbankingRdd` has data as `(CustomerId, nbankingField1, nbankingField2, ....)`

We perform different transformations on each individual rdd, however we need to perform a transformation on the data from all the 3 rdds by grouping  `CustomerId`.

Example: `(CustomerId,debitFiedl1,creditField2,bankingField1,....)`

Is there any way we can group the data from all RDDs based on same key.

Note: In Apache Beam it can be done by using `coGroupByKey`, just checking if there is such alternative available in spark.

Comment: I clearly mentioned what was expected, it has nothing to do with sample data. Not sure why this was down voted.

Comment: I think you could join all the rdds and then group it.

Comment: Not sure it's equivalent to Apache Beam's coGroupByKey, Spark `RDD[K, V]` does have [cogroup](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions@cogroup[W1,W2](other1:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,W1)],other2:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,W2)],numPartitions:Int):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,(Iterable[V],Iterable[W1],Iterable[W2]))]).  Here's a relevant [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43960583/whats-the-difference-between-join-and-cogroup-in-apache-spark).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `cogroup`

```
debitcardRdd.keyBy(_.CustomerId).cogroup(
  creditcardRdd.keyBy(_.CustomerId),
  netbankingRdd.keyBy(_.CustomerId)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to the below, the .keyBy is not imho actually required here and we note that cogroup - not well described can extend to n RDDs.

```
val rddREScogX = rdd1.cogroup(rdd2,rdd3,rddn, ...)
```

Points should go to the first answer.